# SSH into an Orange Pi connected to the internet via 2G GSM module

Tags: networking, communication, linux, gsm

I wanted to SSH into my Orange Pi remotely. It will be connected to the Internet via a 2G GSM module. How should I go about it? Usually it's **ssh username@ip address**. The setup isn't implemented yet so wanted to know if such access is possible. Also suggestions are welcome if a better setup is possible.

I am trying to build a node which I can access remotely. Not trying to do anything particular but it's a learning thing. At first, I will just try to get sensor data (sensor attached to GPIO) and the SSH access was to update code remotely / make changes to the running Python script etc.

Answer (score 7):

Most cellular providers use Private IP (RFC-1918) ranges (e.g. 10.0.0.0/8) and NAT for their networks which means it is not possible to directly access a device connected via these networks remotely as it is behind a proxy server. Even if they are using fully routed networks the IP addresses are handed out dynamically and can change at any time.

Having said that many networks do provide special tariffs that provide a publicly routed fixed IP address. These sims tend to be part of a M2M (Machine 2 Machine) offering and are a lot more expensive than a normal tariff.

Comment: what will i have to do to make it work without these M2M sim cards ? will using something like a VPN work ?

Comment: Yes, if you run your own VPN server that would work as that would provide a route to the device. You can also do something like reverse SSH tunneling via a public machine